# Is it possible to center orthogonal polynomials in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity, polynomial, intercept

I have a regression model that looks like the one below.
$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1T + \beta_2T^2 + \beta_3T^3 + \beta_4D + \beta_5D*T + \beta_6D*T^2 + \beta_7D*T^3
$$

Where `T` is a time variable, which starts from 0 - the starting point, and `T^2` and `T^3` are the natural polynomials of `T`; `D` is a dummy variable.

`T`, `T^2`, and `T^3` are highly collinear. To reduce collinearity, one possible option is to use orthogonal polynomials. However, one issue I have with using orthogonal polynomials is that the intercept of the orthogonal polynomial regression is no longer the predicted value of `Y` at `T = 0` (and when `D = 0`).

I crucially need the intercept to indicate the mean value of `Y` at `T = 0` because of theoretical importance.

#### So my questions are:

#### 1). Is it possible to center orthogonal polynomials in some way (e.g., centering around the minimum value??) so that the intercept will be equivalent to the mean value of `Y` when T= 0`  But I am not sure how this can be properly done given that there are a quadratic term and a cubic term involved.

#### 2). If the answer to the previous question is "No", I wonder if there are any alternative ways in which I can deal with multicollinearity while making the intercept mean what I want it to mean - namely B0 = mean of Y when T = 0 (and D = 0).

Comment: It all depends on which sets of orthogonal polynomials you choose. For instance, after orthogonalizing $\{T,T^2,T^3\}$ you can just subtract their means and you will be fine. Also, the principal reason $\{T, T^2, T^3\}$ will look collinear lies in your choice of origin and scale for time; if you choose an origin somewhere in the middle of the time range, you won't have any such problem. A deeper concern is about this choice of model: unless you have a very good scientific reason to suppose $Y$ is a cubic function of time, this may be an inferior choice of models.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the reply. I do not choose the middle of the time as the origin because I need the origin to be the minimum of time (in other words, the starting point of time in the actual data), which is why there is the issue of collinearity. Regarding centering: you said that subtracting their means should be fine, does this mean that I could also subtract their respective minimums - since I need the intercept to be the mean of Y at the starting point in time. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: In that case you are doomed, because it will be difficult to distinguish between the intercept and a particular near-constant linear combination of $\{T, T^2, T^3\}$. Although the model can be fit, the standard error in the intercept can be extremely large when the origin is well before the minimum value of $T$ in the dataset. In effect this is exactly the same problem of forecasting a polynomial model far into the future, only in reverse (back in time): the uncertainties will be huge.